# MOSFET identification for hoverboard repair - markings SW FK2J3 95N68A

Tags: mosfet, identification, replacement

I am trying to fix a Jetson Plasma hoverboard.

I have a removed a few MOSFETs  that I believe have failed.

I have searched Digikey and Mouser and have been unable to identify a replacement part.

Here are the markings on the part:

SW
FK2J3
95N68A

From what I can gather, this is an N-channel power MOSFET with a 95 V Vds and a max drain current (Id) of 68 A.

Am I close, and can I place this part with any transistor that meets these requirements?

[image: photo of component]

3 pins were removed (they broke during removal).

Comment: Please post a good pic of the part and dimensions

Comment: The part is most likely coming from some Chinese supplier and their products are often not distributed outside of China. The hoverboard actually do not need that kind of current nor the voltage, the key is look for low Rds(on) value, so that it generate less heat during operation. One alternative is [IRF3205Z](https://www.infineon.com/dgdl/Infineon-IRF3205Z-DataSheet-v01_01-EN.pdf?fileId=5546d462533600a4015355df030c190f) which is commonly used in automotive products with low Rds(on) value. You can find it on mouser.

Comment: http://www.tsinghuaicwx.com/images/upfile/file/2019_03/11535241.pdf

Comment: _”MOSFETs that I believe have failed.”_ Engineering 101 - don’t believe, measure.